# Unable to change the Lidar Scan data color in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am running Ros noetic on a RP4 and ubuntu 20 and connect to it using another ubuntu running in VM. I can see the reading from lidar in VM rviz however the color is white when i run the rviz on the RP4 directly the color is red I also can change the color to something else however on the VM no matter what i do I am unable to do that. any idea what could be the issue and how to solve it ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370740/unable-to-change-the-lidar-scan-data-color-in-rviz/) by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2021-02-01

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-02-01**:
I'm not quite sure I understand your problem...
The color of a LaserScan is only in the visualization. I.e. you can set it in the `rviz` LaserScan Display. You have to set the visualization parameters in the `rviz` Windows where you want to view the Laserscan. Check the `Color Transformer` and the relevant color properties...

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-02-01**:
I have run into the same/similar issue on native Ubuntu desktops.  In hopes of clarifying, in case you or someone else has info to add:
The `LaserScan` display worked aside from the rendering.  Even with `Color Transformer` set to `FlatColor`, the color was white no matter what I did with the color property.  Also, the rendered size wouldn't change despite changing that property.  It always looked like the default size (0.01 m).  Running the same software on a different machine worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen this on a few different computers, and the problem for me has always been graphics drivers.  I'm not sure about your setup, but I was able to fix one (18.04, NVIDIA GTX 980) by switching to NVIDIA drivers, instead of using the default Ubuntu driver (Nouveau).  I don't remember the specific steps (e.g., `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450`, restart, etc.), but there are plenty of tutorials, like [this one](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) (not an endorsement).  Here's my driver selection in `Software & Updates` for reference:

[image: image description]

Obviously, this will depend on your graphics card and VM configuration.  Some VMs require extra effort to use the native hardware.

P.S. Solving the issue may only be a side effect of changing the drivers as I never came across a more specific solution, but it worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lslabon](https://answers.ros.org/users/59110/lslabon/) on 2021-02-11**:
Had a similar problem and it worked for me :)! (my laptop couldn't cahnge any laser_scan data (color, size, etc), remote PC could)